# Get `scrapy` to produce a nested datastructure

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, generator

I am using `scrapy` to crawl [this](https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/) website and scrape data

I want the scraped data to have a nested structure. something like this

```js
{
    denomination1: {
        
        date1: {
            bondNumbers: [...] },
        
        date2: {
            bondNumbers: [...] },
        
        ...                    },
    
    denomination2: {
        
        date1: {
            bondNumbers: [...] },
        
        date2: {
            bondNumbers: [...] },
        
        ...                    },
   
   ...
}
```

here is the `spider` I wrote.

```py
import scrapy

class Savings(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'savings'
    start_urls  = [
        'https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        for option in response.css('select option'):
            denomination = option.css('::text').get()
            url          = option.css('::attr(value)').get()
            yield {
                denomination: response.follow(url, self.parseDrawList)
            }


    def parseDrawList(self, response):

        for a in response.css('select option'):            
            date = a.css('::text').get()
            url  = a.css('::attr(value)').get()
            yield {
                date: response.follow(url, self.parseDraw)
            }


    def parseDraw(self, response):
        yield {
            'bondNumbers': response.selector.re(r'\d{6}'),
        }
```

each function is scraping a different page in the web-page hierarchy (if we could call it that), so as a result each level of the nested data-structure would be populated by data from a page of different level.

this code is not working and is giving me an error.

from all the tutorials and documentations i have seen, none have ever used `scrapy` to generate a nested data-structure.

is there any way to get nested data from `scrapy`?. I would also like if the solution does not sacrifice `scrapy`'s concurrent execution of requests

Answer (score 0):

You would need to take the information acquired from each callback and pass it to the next one using either the request meta dictionary or the cb_kwargs parameter in `response.follow` then in the final callback you can construct the fully nested structure and yield it as an item.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class Savings(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'savings'
    start_urls  = [
        'https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for option in response.css('select option'):
            denomination = option.css('::text').get()
            url          = option.css('::attr(value)').get()
            yield response.follow(url, self.parseDrawList, cb_kwargs={'denomination': denomination})

    def parseDrawList(self, response, denomination=None):
        for a in response.css('tr td a'):
            date = a.css('::text').get()
            url  = a.css('::attr(href)').get()
            yield response.follow(url, self.parseDraw, cb_kwargs={'denomination': denomination, "date": date})

    def parseDraw(self, response, denomination=None, date=None):
        yield {
            denomination: {
                date: {
                    'bondNumbers': response.selector.re(r'\d{6}')
                }
            }
        }
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/16-02-2015Rs.1500.txt>
{'Rs. 1500/- Draws': {'16-02-2015': {'bondNumbers': ['749492', '457346', '692793', '914362', '000535', ...]}}}
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/10-03-2021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt> from <GET http://savings.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/10-03-2
021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt>
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/10-12-2021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt> (referer: None)
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/10-12-2021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt>
{'Rs 25000/- Premium Bonds Draws': {'10-12-2021': {'bondNumbers': ['016253', '067408', '038203', '171265', '551833', '655804', '916353', '001858', '064668', '149237', '220908', '293362', '361338', '447697', '512113', '610773', ... ]}}}
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/10-03-2021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt> (referer: None)
2023-08-29 15:40:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk:443/wp-content/uploads/10-03-2021-Rs-25000-Premium.txt>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, although this answer has some useful information but it doesent solve the problem, my question might have not properly communicated the structure of the data properly, i have updated the question to be more clear

Comment: @hammi you could use the same method i have demonstrated in my answer in order to get the data to look like it is in your question, however you it would render the asynchronous aspect of scrapy useless.  It isn't possible to get data in a nested structure and be asynchronous.  If it must be in a nested structure then you will need to do it in a postprocessing procedure.